# Perl Regex Variable Replacement printing 1 instead of desired extraction

Tags: regex, perl, variables, perl5.8

**Case 1:**

```
year$ = ($whole =~ /\d{4}/);
print ("The year is $year for now!";)
```

*Output: The year is The year is 1 for now!*

**Case 2:**

```
$whole="The year is 2020 for now!";
$whole =~ /\d{4}/;
$year =  ($whole);
print ("The year is $year for now!";)
```

*Output: The year is The year is 2020 for now! for now!*

Is there anyway to make the $year variable just 2020?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the match using parenthesis, and assign it to the `$year` all in one step:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $whole = "The year is 2020 for now!";
my ( $year ) =  $whole =~ /(\d{4})/;
print "The year is $year for now!\n";
# Prints:
# The year is 2020 for now!
```

Note that I added this to your code, to enable catching errors, typos,  unsafe constructs, etc, which prevent the code you showed from running:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to capture it into a group

```
$whole="The year is 2020 for now!";
$whole =~ m/(\d{4})/;
$year =  $1;
print ("The year is $year for now!");
```

Comment: Ideally, you don't want to use `$1` without confirming that a match has occurred (since it can lead to weird, hard to debug results), especially since it's so easy to do (as seen in Timur's answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to capture it. Which is somewhat similar to @PYPL's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64003497/6124824).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $whole = "The year is 2020 for now!";

my $year;
($year = $1) if($whole =~ /(\d{4})/);

print $year."\n";
print "The year is $year for now!";
```

**Output:**

```
2020
The year is 2020 for now!
```

Comment: This is better than PYPL's answer because it doesn't use `$1` without confirming that a match has occurred, but see Timur's answer for a much cleaner way of doing the same thing.